# How to take only positive elements for decreasing parallel iterator in Rayon

Tags: rust, parallel-processing, iterator, rayon

I have a Rayon parallel iterator that generates a decreasing sequence of i32 values. At some moment values in this iterator becomes negative. I want to stop iteration at this point and minimize the amount of needless computations.

Since rayon uses size_hint to split an iterator into parts I probably should implement some trait for ParallelIterator and make something like binary search.

I have tried implementing this trait, but it turns out to be quite a difficult task. Is there an easier way?

Comment: I think you may want to use a short circuiting iterator from itertools and then bridge it to a parallel iterator with par_bridge()

Comment: You should show more of what you tried, and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)